# How to declare embedded body parameters in swagger yaml format

Tags: web-services, rest, swagger

I have a sample request input with  the nested post parameters in JSON which looks like below.  I have to know use this data to create definition in YAML format but I have no idea how to do this.

I have read the swagger docs but still can't crack this.

```
"clientAttributes" : [ {
"id" : "1",
"clientDetail" : [ {
  "clientNum" : "98062217",
  "clientCntryCd" : "55",
  "clientTypeList" : [ {
    "clientTypeCd" : "HomePhone",
    "cntryCd" : ""
  } ]
} ]} ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good example is the `Pet` object defined in [petstore.yaml](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml#L654), which contains 2 objects as the properties: `category`, `tags`

For your case, you will need to define `clientAttributes`, `clientDetail`, `clientTypeList` as objects.